What is a Sannyasis dharma towards his mother ? Which scripture tells rules about it?
As far as I know Sannyasis are supposed to do Namaskaram to their mothers. But which scripture say this?

In srimad bhagavatam sanyaasi role has been said but I don't know where is said to do dandvat pranam https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/7/13/advanced-view/ , I have heard from saints that you must do dandvat pranam to your mother if by chance you met her (she came to meet somehow) and never take their money and never go back home or live with your family after sanyaasa
